# Web3.js and MetaMask ethereum.request: is it possible to specify specific crypto/token used to pay?

Tags: web3js, javascript

I will have a few "Click to Pay" buttons on a website that accepts crypto, using web3.js and MetaMask. I want to make sure different buttons automatically direct the user to use different currencies, such as ETH, MATIC, and other ERC-20 tokens, etc.

I'm not sure how to do this with the following code, which seems to work with whatever network the user is connected to:

```
const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
const account = accounts[0];
console.log(account);   
var hex_value = '0x'+parseInt(my_input['amount'], 10).toString(16); // gets me the right value in hex

const transactionParameters = {
    from: account,
    to: MyContractAddr,
    data: MyContract.methods.processPayment(
        my_input['name'],
        my_input['amount'],
        my_input['date']
    ).encodeABI(),
    value: hex_value,
};
// popup - request the user to sign and broadcast the transaction
await ethereum.request({
    method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
    params: [transactionParameters],
});
```

How can I make the above specific to a particular cryptocurrency, e.g. ETH or MATIC? It seems to work fine with either, but as the user on the website, I manually select which network I am and which currency I'm using via MetaMask, so I'm confused. I want this to be decided automatically rather than the user being able to pay "20 units" of "whatever" crypto. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

If you look at the definition of a transaction using web3js, you will see that you can select which blockchain you are referring to (chain). Note that you are also defining an address, and if the user chooses another blockchain (in principle he can do this, although not through this transaction, as you are now defining the chain), he will be interacting with the right address on the 'wrong' network, i.e. he will probably be sending money to an account that no one has the private key.